# Call static method in another class library

Tags: c#

How to call static method in another class library? Because I created 2 class library Common and another call DAL, and I already add Commmon dll reference in my DAL class library, after that I cannot find out my method name. Isn't got other method to solve it?

Class library : Common

```
using System;

    namespace Common
    {
        public class Log
        {
            public static bool Error(Exception ex)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Class library : DAL

```
using Common
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class MenuD
    {
        Log.;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call the `Log.Error()` method from that location in the class, outside of a method.

Call it from within a method in the `MenuD` class.

```
public class MenuD
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // do something that could throw an exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var isLogged = Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, my mistake forget open a function and call it.